# IIS web.config Old URL to New URL redirects

Tags: iis, redirect, rewrite, web.config

I'm new to redirects and having a hard time getting these to work, I have about 1400 URL's from an old site that need to redirect to a new site, same domain name, but different folders and domain strings. Here's what I have that currently does not work, any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

```
<rule name="Redirect0001" patternSyntax="ExactMatch" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="www.sitename.com/index.html/_10_12_Slotted_Screwdriver_Bit_2_long?SCREEN=product_ordering&amp;ScreenID=2464&amp;ProductID=952" />                 
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="www.sitename.com/index.html/_10_12_Slotted_Screwdriver_Bit_2_long?SCREEN=product_ordering&amp;ScreenID=2464&amp;ProductID=952" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.sitename.com/items.aspx?category=Screwdriver+Bits%2c+Nutsetters+%26+Holders&amp;id=203" />  
                </rule>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of things.

1. You only want to match things after the / in the match url
2. You don't want to include the query string in the match url

So, give this rule a try.  It matches beginning with `index.html/...` and uses the Query String in the match conditions.

```
<rule name="Redirect0001" patternSyntax="ExactMatch" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="index.html/_10_12_Slotted_Screwdriver_Bit_2_long" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="SCREEN=product_ordering&amp;ScreenID=2464&amp;ProductID=952" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.mysite.com/items.aspx?category=Screwdriver+Bits%2c+Nutsetters+%26+Holders&amp;id=203" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
```

Adding 1400 of these seems rather tedious, though.  I would look to see if there is a way you can break them into query string patterns.

Comment: Thanks so much, this worked perfectly, appreciate the help.

Comment: I was going to ask you that, I did notice that there are a few of the pages that are different URL's but do need to redirect to the same page, what's the way to do that?  If I could set those up as 1 rule that would at least cut down on total rules to set up.

Comment: Example: all these redirect to same page..

Comment: OLD
http://www.mysite.com/index.html/_32_New_Gray_Knit_Rags_8_lb_net_wt_carton?SCREEN=product_ordering&ScreenID=3090&ProductID=1063
http://www.mysite.com/index.html/_41_New_White_T_Shirt_Wiping_Rags_22_5_lb_net_wt_carton?SCREEN=product_ordering&ScreenID=3090&ProductID=1061
http://www.mysite.com/index.html/_41_New_White_T_Shirt_Wiping_Rags_8_lb_net_wt_carton?SCREEN=product_ordering&ScreenID=3090&ProductID=1064
http://www.mysite.com/index.html/_45_New_Looped_Knit_Rags_8_lb_net_wt_carton?SCREEN=product_ordering&ScreenID=3090&ProductID=1065

Comment: NEW
http://www.mysite.com/items.aspx?category=Rags&id=86